# I want to find the lowest difference within the group and return the index.(Python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

This is my df.

```
index   firmcode    year    indcode     ROA
  0      a         2006      03         0.1
  1      b         2006      03         0.2
  2      c         2006      03         0.4
  3      d         2006      03         0.7   
  4      e         2006      07         0.3
  5      f         2006      07         0.8
  6      g         2006      07         1.1
  7      h         2006      07         2.1
```

I would like it to be as follows(Except for the same company).
This is ROA matching the nearest company(in same year, same indcode)

```
index   firmcode    year    indcode     ROA   diff_min_firmcode
  0      a         2006      03         0.1         b  
  1      b         2006      03         0.2         a
  2      c         2006      03         0.4         b          
  3      d         2006      03         0.7         c
  4      e         2006      07         0.3         f 
  5      f         2006      07         0.8         g 
  6      g         2006      07         1.1         f
  7      h         2006      07         2.1         g
```

How can I get the `df['diff_min_firmcode']` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use custom function for subtract each value `ROA` per groups, set `NaN`s to diagonal for omit same company and then use [`DataFrame.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
def f(x):
    y = x['ROA'].to_numpy()
    arr = np.abs(y - y[:, None])
    np.fill_diagonal(arr, np.nan)
    z = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=x['firmcode'], columns=x.index)
    return z.idxmin()

df['diff_min_firmcode'] = df.groupby(['year','indcode'], group_keys=False).apply(f)

print (df)
  firmcode  year  indcode  ROA diff_min_firmcode
0        a  2006        3  0.1                 b
1        b  2006        3  0.2                 a
2        c  2006        3  0.4                 b
3        d  2006        3  0.7                 c
4        e  2006        7  0.3                 f
5        f  2006        7  0.8                 g
6        g  2006        7  1.1                 f
7        h  2006        7  2.1                 g
```

Comment: It works very well!! You are very kind and smart! I hope good things happen to you soon. Thank you!!